# How can I pass data from jQuery to php for saving into a database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've read about the jQuery.ajax method and believe this should be what I need -- but so far can't get it to work.

I created a test mysql database with a table called "users", added rows to that table for "name" and "location", and then made sure I could save data to it using the command line, which I could. Then I made a test page with a button on it and added this copy to my scripts file (the $.ajax part comes straight from the jQuery api examples):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    saveData();
});

function saveData(){  
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
   url: "process.php",
   data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
 alert( "Data was saved: " + msg );
    });
}
```

I do indeed get an alert message, "Data was saved", but nothing has actually been saved to my database. I must be doing something wrong with process.php, but not sure what. Here's the code in process.php (I set variables for database, db_host, user, etc that I don't display here):

```
// 1. Create a connection to the server. 
$connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user,$db_pwd);

// make sure a connection has been made
if (!$connection){
die("Database connection failed: " . mysql.error());
}

// 2. Select the database on the server
$db_select = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_select){
die("Database selection failed: " . mysql.error());
}

// START FORM PROCESSING
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
    $name = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['name']));
$location = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['location']));

// INSERT THE DATA 
$query = "INSERT INTO user ( name, location )
              VALUES ( '{$name}','{$location}' )";
        // Confirm if the query is successful.
        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
}
```

Comment: Proper indentation is important...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's has already been told by others, about using 'success' and 'error' which would be indeed a better method to capture the success/error callback. But that's really not the problem why nothing is inserted. Your Ajax call looks good besides that.

Another problem that i see is that you're only passing the following params:

```
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
```

But in your PHP code you do check if a submit button was set:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

This is obviously not the case because the only things that are sent are the things you pass in the 'data' attribute of the Ajax call. Instead use:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
```

Comment: That worked, so thanks! I hadn't realized that's what was going on with: if (isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: @adamKiryk Then maybe it's a good idea to atleast accept this as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this example, $_POST['submit'] is not set because you are no sending the form as usual, you are rsendin data with ajax and there isn't any variable called "submit".

This may work better:

```
if ((isset($_POST['name'])) && (isset($_POST['location']))) { // Form has been submitted.
    $name = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['name']));
$location = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['location']));

// INSERT THE DATA 
$query = "INSERT INTO user ( name, location )
              VALUES ( '{$name}','{$location}' )";
        // Confirm if the query is successful.
        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Done" doesn't mean "succeeded".  Instead of done:, use this to see if it finished successfully or not:

```
success: function(data)
    {
       alert(data);
    },
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert("Error Status: " + xhr.status + " Thrown Errors: "+thrownError);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

all that

```
.done(function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data was saved: " + msg );
});
```

is telling you is that the ajax request is done. Your probably need to look at `.success` instead. Additionally, your code doesn't show this so I'm assuming that it's not doing this but in order for `msg` to have anything in your `php` needs to actually return something. (`PHP` people help me out with this I'm a `.Net` guy helping with the `JS` :) )

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple mistake. You left `submit` while posting to process.php while you are checking its existence before updating DB

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    saveData();
});

function saveData(){  
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
   url: "process.php",
   data: { name: "John", location: "Boston",submit:"submit" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
 alert( "Data was saved: " + msg );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't submitting via a traditional form, but using ajax, I suspect submit isn't part of the post. Check that by putting in the following else clause to your code. If you're hitting that die statement, then remove the if test

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
    $name = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['name']));
$location = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['location']));

// INSERT THE DATA 
$query = "INSERT INTO user ( name, location )
              VALUES ( '{$name}','{$location}' )";
        // Confirm if the query is successful.
        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
} else {
  die("$_POST['submit'] didn't exist");
}
```